# Teechart HTML5/Javascript value ticker to stay on Tee.Line series

Tags: javascript, html, teechart

I am not able to make tickers stay above the line like this 
 [Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H8BsGepxaldWZ3X19ma3lhb00/view?usp=sharing)

This is my code

```
function draw() {
var Chart1=new Tee.Chart("canvas");
Chart1.title.text="Test Line";
Chart1.footer.text=""; 
Chart1.title.format.font.style="16px Verdana";
Chart1.footer.format.font.style="10px Verdana";
Chart1.applyTheme("minimal");
Chart1.palette.colors[0] ="blue"
Chart1.palette.colors[1] ="red"
Chart1.palette.colors[2] ="green"
Chart1.palette.colors[3] ="yellow"

tip=new Tee.ToolTip(Chart1);
tip.format.font.style="14px Tahoma";
tip.render="canvas";
Chart1.tools.add(tip);

Chart1.addSeries(new Tee .Line([]) ); 
var Series0 =     Chart1.series.items[0];
Series0.marks.style="value";
Series0.colorEach="no";
Series0.format.stroke.size=3;
Series0.pointer.visible=true; 
Series0.title='2013' ;
Series0.data.values[0] =402;
Series0.data.labels[0] ='1';
Series0.data.values[1] =454;
Series0.data.labels[1] ='2';
Series0.data.values[2] =474;
Series0.data.labels[2] ='3';
Series0.data.values[3] =618;
Series0.data.labels[3] ='4';

Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line([]) ); 
var Series1 =      Chart1.series.items[1];
Series1.marks.style="value";
Series1.colorEach="no";
Series1.format.stroke.size=3;
Series1.pointer.visible=true;
Series1.title='2014';
Series1.data.values[0] =623;
Series1.data.labels[0] ='1';
Series1.data.values[1] =653;
Series1.data.labels[1] ='2';
Series1.data.values[2] =631;
Series1.data.labels[2] ='3';
Series1.data.values[3] =248;
Series1.data.labels[3] ='4';

Chart1.draw();
}
```

the result looks like this [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H8BsGepxalVnVMUlFTTkoxMnc/view?usp=sharing)   missing the tickets over the line , I would like them to always stay on the line.

Is it possible

B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "minimal" theme hides the bottom axis grid. If you want to make it visible again you can call this later:

```
Chart1.axes.bottom.grid.visible=true;
```

The "minimal" theme also hides the series marks. If you want to make them visible again you can call this later:

```
Series0.marks.visible=true;
Series1.marks.visible=true;
```